# In EF Core, is there any way to prevent writing same conditions in queries and make an expression instead?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

If there were same conditions I had to use in many queries, is there a way to write something like an expression and use it in all that queries?

For example:

Query1:

```
Context.Products.Where(p => p.active && !p.deleted && !p.hidden && //other conditions)
```

Query2:

```
Context.Products.Where(p => p.active && !p.deleted && !p.hidden && //other conditions)
```

Query3:

```
Context.Products.Where(p => p.active && !p.deleted && !p.hidden && //other conditions)
```

There are duplicated conditions used in all queries:

> p.active && !p.deleted && !p.hidden

So what if I could write them once and use for each query something like:

> conditions(method, expression, or ...) = p.active && !p.deleted &&
> !p.hidden
>
> Context.Products.Where(p => conditions && //other conditions)

Any idea?

Comment: Do you prefer IQueryable<Product> or DbSet<Product> ? Depending on which, you could make an extension method.

Comment: IQueryable<Product> @Fildor

Comment: If such conditions are all related to the same element type (`Product` in your examples), you can create a method (maybe an extension, as suggested by @Fildor) that attach the specific `Where` to an input query). If you need it on several element types, than you might need to declare the common properties in a new interface, implemented by the involved element type classes, and make such method generic based on such interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Context.Products` is a `DbSet<Product>`:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
// Pick your preferred name, this is just to showcase
    public static IQueryable<Product> Valid (this IQueryable<Product> unfiltered)
       => unfiltered.Where(p => p.active)
                    .Where(p => !p.deleted)
                    .Where(p => !p.hidden)
                 // ... more 

      // you can also write it like this:
      // unfiltered.Where(p => p.active && !p.deleted && !p.hidden)
}
```

Usage

```
var filtered = await Context.Products.AsQueryable().Valid().ToListAsync();
```

Note: This is different from [@Magnus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77953307/982149) solely in that this is implemented as [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). So they should be largely functional identical.

---

There are also [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) in EF Core. But I don't know if that's what you are looking for. They have *some* quirks and downsides, so I am hesitant to recommend those.

Basically they add a filter on *all* queries. And if you don't want it you need to opt-out explicitly.

Docs comprehend them as follows:

> Global query filters are LINQ query predicates applied to Entity Types in the metadata model (usually in OnModelCreating). A query predicate is a boolean expression typically passed to the LINQ Where query operator. **EF Core applies such filters automatically to any LINQ queries involving those Entity Types.** EF Core also applies them to Entity Types, referenced indirectly through use of Include or navigation property. Some common applications of this feature are:
>
> Soft delete - An Entity Type defines an IsDeleted property.
> Multi-tenancy - An Entity Type defines a TenantId property.

(emphasis by me)

My personal experience with those: Using them *can* sometimes lead to confusion. What do I mean by that: In our code base, we have gqfs in place *and* in *some* cases opt-out. Now, **if you don't *carefully* document that** it is not uncommon to make frequent diving trips through the code to find out if the filter is actually used or not in what you are currently writing ...

Answer (score 5):

You could extract it to a function.

```
GetActiveProducts(Context.Products).Where(p => ...)

public static IQueryable<Product> GetActiveProducts(IQueryable<Product> products) => 
    products.Where(p => p.active && !p.deleted && !p.hidden);
```

Answer (score 0):

With many thanks to @Fildor, and consider showing my products is related to more conditions related to other entities, my final extension method goes like this:

```
public static class ProductFilters
{
    public static IQueryable<Product> Shown(this IQueryable<Product> prd, int langId)
        => prd.Where(p => p.Active && !p.RecordDeleted && !p.Hidden &&
            p.ProductAttributes.Any(pa => pa.LanguageId.Equals(langId) && pa.Active && !pa.RecordDeleted &&
                pa.ProductCategory != null && pa.ProductCategory.Active && !pa.ProductCategory.RecordDeleted));
}
```

And usage:

```
public async Task<int> GetCondithinedProductsCount(int langId)
{
    return await Context.Products.Shown(langId)
        .Where(p => ...)
        .CountAsync();
}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: You could also rename GetCondithinedProductsCount() to GetCondithinedProductsCountAsync() - that way callers know they are dealing with an async method.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with approach like to assign the common into variable and reuse, use `Predicate<T>` where `T` is the type of your `p`

```
var predicate = p => p.active && !p.deleted && !p.hidden;
```

and then

```
Context.Products.Where(p => predicate(p) && p.Items > 0)
```

Comment: Have you actually tried that?